# How to Use preg_match for New Line

Tags: php

I prevent people from entering characters other than the one on preg_match with this code:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/",$input)) {
    $error = "Error";
}
```

**It only permits:**

- A to Z
- 0 to 9
- (space)

But, if people click ENTER. data can not be sent. How do I have to change the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use \r\n for enter or new line in preg_match.

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9 \r\n]*$/",$input)) {
    $error = "Error";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
&[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]&
```

the \s should find any type of whitespace, including newlines and spaces. if you only want spaces and newlines (not tabs or other whitespace) you can do `/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think the above will work fine... but if it fails you can try this:

```
if (!preg_match("/(?!\n)^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*$/",$input)) {
    $error = "Error";
}
```

**(?!\n)** Negative look ahead will prevent \n from appearing in the string..